# LDAPException when trying to connect using userPrincipalName

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldapconnection

We made a new enhancement to the client around LDAP, to enable login using `userPrincipalName`. He was earlier using `sAMAccountName` for login. When the user tried to test the application in his test environment, he is getting the following error for `userPrincipalName`:

> netscape.ldap.LDAPException: error result (49); 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v23f0 |#]

Which I know is because of invalid credentials of LDAP. But, when he is logging using `sAMAccountName` he is able to login.

My web application logs shows that when he is login with `userPrincipalName`, it is found in the LDAP but when it tries to connect to LDAP with the username and password, then the above exception is thrown.

Whereas, he is able to successfully login using `sAMAccountName`.

The Dn's used as something like below:

```
OU=IS (Technical Staff),OU=PXXX,DC=pxxx,DC=local , and
OU=Users,OU=PXXX,DC=pxxx,DC=local
```

Any help to further debug the issue would be highly appreciated.

Please let me know in case you need further details.

- domain is like pxxx.local
- userPrincipalName is like abc.xyz@pxxx.org.uk.

Do I need to make any changes for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. The problem was that for sAMAccountName, you need to append the LDAP Domain for login when I am trying to login from my java application.

Where as for userPrincipalName, if you append the LDAP Domain, the login fails.

So, modified code such that for userPrincipalName, We are not appending the LDAP Domain, which resolved the issue.

Comment: Nitin, could you add some examples (how they look like) of what worked for you and what did not?

Comment: an example of what worked would make this more helpful

Comment: My issue solved when I appended the domain to the username, for example if the username was `Administrator` and domain was `xyz.com`, the username I used for login was `Administrator@xyz.com`